# How can I specify a custom reset password URL for Auth0 Lock iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, auth0

I'm trying to specify a custom reset password URL using the [Auth0 Lock iOS SDK](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX).

This is easy to do using the web SDK, it's just a configuration parameter passed into the `Auth0Lock` constructor as `options` (docs [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#forgotpasswordlink-string-)).

However, I'm struggling to find anything similar on the iOS SDK.

Short of hacking Auth0 classes in the iOS SDK, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation there is no support to customize Lock for iOS in the way you describe. It's possible do hide the default reset password functionality, but if you need to go beyond that it seems you'll need to provide your own custom UI.

Reference: [Lock iOS: Password Reset](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/password-reset-ios)

Comment: This is the same conclusion that I've arrived at, unfortunately. Thank you for confirming this as well.